# Setting a local variable in MySQL no longer works

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, wavemaker

I use a user variable in MySQL to control the operation of triggers in my database. These variables are set in a service with the following Java code:

```
    MedicalDB service = (MedicalDB)RuntimeAccess.getInstance().getServiceBean("medicalDB"); // medicaldb is the name of the connection to DB
    try {
        service.begin();
        Session session = service.getDataServiceManager().getSession();

        sql = "SET @disableTriggers = 0;";
        session.createQuery(sql).executeUpdate(); <---- Throws null pointer exception
```

This code has worked properly for a long time but now when the service executes the executeUpdate() method it throws a null pointer exception. The issue is with the SET statement since, if I comment it out, subsequent sql statements function properly.

Has something changed with the JRE (build 1.7.0-03-b05) or Hibernate. I am using Wavemaker 6.4.6GA

Comment: What have you updated on your project lately? Java, hibernate, MySQL it self, etc.

Comment: The JRE was updated to 1.7. Wavemaker comes with 1.6 JDK I believe. I have been working with Jasper reports and I downloaded JAVA SDK 1.7 . Hibernate and MYSQL are unchanged as far as I know. The SQL executes properly in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: If you break that line up, where is the exception thrown. Meaning I am wondering if the `session` is null (probably not) or if the `createQuery(sql)` call is returning null or if the nullpointer is happening in the `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: I'll try breaking it up. I did trace the code and the session is not null it is OK.

Comment: I am figured that, I was just not sure if the createQuery is where it is breaking down or not.

Comment: I modified the code and the null pointer is thrown when creating the query:             sql = "SET `@disableTriggers`=0;";
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql); <-- Exception thrown here.
            query.executeUpdate();

Comment: Are you using `createQuery` or `createSQLQuery`? Which ever one you are using try the other. This is just guess work, by the way. The next step is to go look at the hibernate source code and see what in the hell is null in there to throw the exception.

Comment: I have tried both. I started out with createSQLQuery.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your post.

Comment: Basically it is the full exception that is thrown, the output is usually thrown into a log file somewhere. depends on your setup though.

Comment: 2012-10-22 15:17:24,092 DEBUG [org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction] - <begin> (session 417AFF923EF0F56AFAEE5030705CBDEA, thread 33 invoke WaitTimes.calculateWaitTimes) 
2012-10-22 15:17:24,136 DEBUG [org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction] - <current autocommit status: true> (session 417AFF923EF0F56AFAEE5030705CBDEA, thread 33 invoke WaitTimes.calculateWaitTimes) 
2012-10-22 15:17:24,136 DEBUG [org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction] - <disabling autocommit> (session 417AFF923EF0F56AFAEE5030705CBDEA, thread 33 invoke WaitTimes.calculateWaitTimes)

Comment: 2012-10-22 15:17:37,851 ERROR [WaitTimes] - <The calculateWaitTimes java service operation has failed> (session 417AFF923EF0F56AFAEE5030705CBDEA, thread 33 invoke WaitTimes.calculateWaitTimes) 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.wavemaker.runtime.data.util.QueryHandler$SingleQuery.access$100(QueryHandler.java:592)
 at com.wavemaker.runtime.data.util.QueryHandler.modifySQL(QueryHandler.java:319)
 at com.wavemaker.runtime.data.util.QueryHandler.invoke(QueryHandler.java:86)
 at $Proxy122.createSQLQuery(Unknown Source)
 at WaitTimes.calculateWaitTimes(WaitTimes.java:45)